# Uncaught InvalidStateError. Object's State must be Opened.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED. uber-graph.js:19

However, here is my code. I don't understand why it is wrong.

var uberTemplateFunction = Handlebars.compile($('#page-template').html());

```
var search = function(Slong, Slat, Elong, Elat){

Slat = encodeURIComponent(Slat);
Slong = encodeURIComponent(Slong);
Elat = encodeURIComponent(Elat);
Elong = encodeURIComponent(Elong);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById('ajaxResponse').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};

var url = 'https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=' + Slat  +  '&start_longitude=' + Slong + '&end_latitude=' + Elat + '&end_longitude=' + Elong;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token lFdfJgCSnohPg0LVm8NN3qBviR0-cwl42exRYqAU");
xhr.open('GET', url , true);
xhr.send(); // Make the HTTP request



    $.getJSON(url, function(response){  //can use $ or jQuery
        console.log(response);

        var html = '';

        for(var i = 0; i < response.prices.length; i++){
            html += uberTemplateFunction(response.prices[i]);
        }

        $('#results').html(html);
    });

};
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var Slat = $('#slat').val();
    var Slong = $('#slong').val();
    var Elat = $('#elat').val();
    var Elong = $('#elong').val();

    //console.log(searchTerm);

    $('#results').html('Loading....');
    search(Slat, Slong, Elat, Elong);
});
```

Comment: put setRequestHeader() call after open()

Comment: @progysm I don't have permission then. This is the error that pops up XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=-119&start_longitude=33.716721&end_latitude=-118.4922867&end_longitude=34.0115585. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: @KennyUSC: that's an unrelated issue: the API should be used by your server, not client-side code.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy so there is no way to display the data from the JSON Uber has provided?

Comment: @KennyUSC Doesn't seem that their API implements CORS.